# NSArray containsObject method inconsistent results

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I have an NSMutableArray called selectedUsers to which I am adding objects using a method called addUser.  The objects being added are most often of type PLManagedUser (a core data managed object) although sometimes the object could be a string.  In any case, if the array already contains the object, I do not want to add it to the array. Here is the code:

```
- (void)addUser:(id)user withTitle:(NSString *)title {

    if (![_selectedUsers containsObject:user]) {
        [_selectedUsers addObject:user];
    }
}
```

I have noticed that if I try to add the same user back to back using the above method, the containsObject catches it, and duplicates are not added. However, if I add the same user (with the same memory address) after having added other objects in between, the duplicate will be added.

I am printing the contents of the array each time I add something to confirm that the duplicate objects are in the array.

My question is, is there any obvious reason why containsObject isn't consistently working here?

Comment: Does `PLManagedUser` implement the `isEqual:` and `hash` methods?

Comment: I should add that I am debugging code I did not write - how would I know this? It inherits from NSObject, so I would think so?

Comment: By default the `isEqual:` method will do a pointer check only; but that doesn't tally with the statements in your question, so perhaps something deeper is happening.

Comment: I think that you have not correctly characterized the problem.

Comment: Once you've made sure that `isEqual:` and `hash` are implemented, consider using an `NSMutableSet` instead of an `NSMutableArray`, this way you don't need to check for yourself if the object is already contained in the collection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide the ability for an object to identify itself as equal to another object of the same class, and to do this you implement the [`isEqual:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isEqual%3a) and [`hash`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/hash) methods.

Having said that, the explanation in your question is the *opposite* of what I would have expected.

Comment: I'd bet adding `isEqual:` and `hash` to `NSManagedObject` subclasses is a **really really bad thing to do**.   Managed objects, IIRC, define equality strictly in terms of the `NSManagedObjectID`.

Comment: @bbum so how would you effectively store managed objects in a collection class?

Comment: Add them and remove 'em as you normally would, just don't redefine their definition of equality.   Though, in general, that one is using various collection collections *not* managed by CD to store CD managed objects is a bit of a code smell;  it indicates that the model layer isn't really capturing the full state of the app.